# How do I modify a sample code for primefactorization in Excel VBA to a specific column of numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

I have in Column K:

```
K8 is 6384 i.e. =SUM(J1:J8)
K9 is 2598 i.e. =SUM(J2:J9)
K10 is 12176 i.e =SUM(J3:J10)
:
:
K5488
```

up to K5488 (No numbers in sequence, all different numbers) 
                   The largest number appearing in K is 1 400 000.

I need in Column M: The prime factors of each number in K
                    e.g. K8 is 6384 then M8 should be 2,2,2,2,3,7,19
                         k9 is 2598 then M9 should be 2,3,433  etc.

I found the following code by John Coleman on your site (Mar 28) which tested well, but seeing I have no programming knowledge, I don't know how to modify it to use in my columns K & M setup.
Here's the sample code:

```
Function Factor(ByVal n As Long, Optional FirstTrial As Long = 2) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim limit As Long
    Dim rest As String
    Dim s As String

    If n = 1 Then
        Factor = n
        Exit Function
    End If
    limit = Int(Sqr(n))
    t = FirstTrial
    Do While t <= limit
        If n Mod t = 0 Then
            rest = Factor(n / t, t)
            If rest <> "1" Then
                s = t & "," & rest
            End If
            Factor = s
            Exit Function
        Else
            If t = 2 Then t = 3 Else t = t + 2
        End If
    Loop
    'if we get here:
    Factor = n
End Function

Function PrimeOrFactor(n As Long) As String
    Dim s As String
    s = Factor(n)
    If n = 1 Then
        PrimeOrFactor = "Neither"
    ElseIf (s) = Trim(n) Then
        PrimeOrFactor = "Prime"
    Else
        PrimeOrFactor = s
    End If
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        Cells(i, 1) = i
        Cells(i, 2) = PrimeOrFactor(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you provided is a udf (user defined function) to be used in your worksheet.

If you put the functions you provided in a normal code module, you can enter the following in your worksheet in M8:

```
=Factor(K8)
```

and copy that function down to your desired range.

Comment: As a Novice Dummy, I seriously appreciate that you took the time to answer my -what must have seemed like a very stupid- question (now that a got the answer) Thanks Jochen!

Comment: John Coleman, what a brilliant code! It works perfect and instant even with huge numbers. Thanks